# Pulling specific values from a List in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm pulling data from a database and storing it in a List, right now when I pull a entry from the list using list.get(index) I'm getting an output of {hours_worked=1.5}.

All I want to get from the database is the 1.5 and not the hours worked.

This is the method I'm using that is retrieving the List:

```
    public List totalHoursByActivity(int custId, int activityId) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    this.openConnection();

    List totalHours = new ArrayList();

    String sqlStmt = "SELECT hours_worked\n"
            + "from work_entry\n"
            + "JOIN activity\n"
            + "ON work_entry.activity_id = activity.activity_id\n"
            + "JOIN customer\n"
            + "ON work_entry.customer_id = customer.customer_id\n"
            + "WHERE customer.customer_id = " + custId + " and activity.activity_id = " + activityId;

    totalHours = db.findRecords(sqlStmt);

    return totalHours;
}
```

Is there a way to go about pulling out just the double from the list? or what might be the best way for pulling that data out and get that value?

Edit: This is what findRecords is:

```
    public List findRecords(String sqlStmt) throws SQLException {
    final List allRecords = new ArrayList();
    Map record = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = null;

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
    metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();

    while (rs.next()) {
        record = new HashMap();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            record.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        allRecords.add(record);
    }

    return allRecords;
}
```

Comment: I wonder what `findRecords` is doing...

Comment: who is the `db` variable? how are you creating your connection? If this is pure JDBC you can use the ResultSet class to get a specif field. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: Put up findRecords() to show what it is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findRecords returns list of maps and each map holds column name as the key and the corresponding value.

In your case the key is 'work_entry' as suggested by the sql statement,
and the value is 1.5, the {hours_worked=1.5} is the default output of the toString method on the map.

If you want time, you need to call totalHours.get(i).get("hours_worked").

If you used generics you would see the objects types.

Comment: the .get("hours_worked") is not an option when I try only .getClass();

Comment: Because you are not using proper typing of your methods.

Comment: You can print out what the getClass() value is and you will see that it is an instance of HashMap. Do the casting to right type. Or fix your declarations to provide proper types for your methods ie List<Map<String,Object> findRecords() ....